# JSL select Query with keyword and parantheses

Tags: sql, select, sas-jmp, jsl

I am trying to select specific values from a column in JSL, but there is an issue. The column name is:

```
Sum(ow_blah)
```

And I would like to: `select where(Sum(ow_blah) == 0)`

Unfortunately, the combination of the keyword `Sum` and parentheses have led to significant problems. And Aliasing is not allowed in `select` statements. How can I use the `Sum` function within a `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

Use `HAVING` after grouping, as in:

```
select id, sum(ow_blah)
  from my_table
  group by id
  having sum(ow_blah) = 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work either, the select keyword isn't recognized unless I specify: dt << select (id, sum(ow_blah) from tablename group by id having sum(ow_blah) = 0 .... and it must be all on one line or the keywords are not recognized. Sorry, never had this problem before

Answer (score 0):

Since "sum" is a keyword, you need to explicitly let JMP know that you are selecting a column by the name Sum(ow_blah). So for that, use it as:

```
Column("Sum(Ow_blah)")
```